# Backbone events not binding to dom element

Tags: events, dom, backbone.js, click

In one of my views I have:

```
events: {
    'click .tab': 'doSomething',
},
```

then:

```
doSomething: function(){
    ...
},
```

This is a recurring structure in my views, but for some reason the 'doSomething' function is not being triggered by the click in this view.

When are the elements being bound to the event?

Any tips on debugging this?

Answer (score 10):

link to fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/7xRak/

Omitting the selector causes the event to be bound to the view's root element (`this.el`).

if your `class="tab"` is views DOM element means `this.el` then you should bind event as

```
events : {
  'click' : 'dosomething'
}
```

and for inner element in `this.el` like

```
<div class="tab">
     <span class="inner"></span>
</div>
```

then you should bind event as,

```
  events : {
      'click' : 'dosomething'
      'click .inner' : 'onInnerClick'
    }
```

document : http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents

Comment: This is exactly what I'm showing above, I'm well aware of this pattern.  What I'm trying to say is that this pattern for some reason is not working, so what are some ways to debug the event delegation.

Answer (score 7):

The delegation happens during the `delegateEvents` method at the end of the view constructor.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-144

Try manually calling `this.delegateEvents()` inside `render` before returning `this`. Are you futzing with `this.el` inside your `initialize` or `render` methods in a way that backbone isn't expecting?

Comment: Hm, I just tried calling the this.delegateEvents() before the return in the render but it's still not binding the events.  Also, I'm not messing with the this.el inside either the initialize or the render.  The only thing that worked was calling                                 var that  = this;                             this.$('.tab').on('click',function(){that.doSomething();});                 inside of the initialize, but this feels like bad form...

Comment: I wasn't messing with $el or el either, but adding delegateEvents to my render fixed the event binding.